In Rust's proc_macro_attribute implementation, filter out custom attribute token in a deeply nested tree
In my #[proc_macro_attribute] implementation of the custom attribute, I need to filter out the #[fix] attribute that may exist on an argument of a function. The custom function gets a input: proc_macro2::TokenStream which has .into_iter() of TokenTree values, but I don't see a clean way to simply copy one stream to another, while filtering something out.  This is similar to #[default] attribute for #[derive(Default)] in the standard library.
#[custom]
mod MyModule {
  pub fn my_func(
     #[fix] arg1 // <-- this is not a real attribute,
                 //     but it gets handled by my proc macro,
                 //     and needs to be filtered out.
  ) { ... }
}


It's unclear where your problem is. If you don't want that attribute to appear in the output, you simply don't emit it. In the stream you'd have to look for the tokens that make up the attribute and omit them. Usually you'd parse the token stream to something workable from syn or a similar crate though.

The tokens you're looking for are [Punct { char: '#', spacing: Alone, }, Group { delimiter: Bracket, stream: TokenStream [ Ident { sym: foo, }, ], }]
